# Что делать если ошибся в очереди проверок?

Tags: обсуждение

Несколько раз я ошибался в очередях (не в проверках на внимательность, а в настоящих вопросах). Что делать если ошибся в очереди проверок?

Comment: Хорошо бы привести в вопросе ссылки на такие проверки.

Comment: Все иногда ошибаются. Ничего не делать, жить с этим.

Comment: Сильно зависит от того, в какой очереди была ошибка, был ли голос решающим или нет.

Comment: @insolor _жить с этим_, я не могу долго жить нося вину за содеянное в сердце.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если гложет совесть:

- Найти в поиске вопрос по упомянутым там словам, либо если осознали ошибку сразу же, то можно нажать кнопку "Назад" в обзорщике.
- Отозвать голос за закрытие или голосовать за переоткрытие, если он был закрыт.
- Голосовать за закрытие, если было выбрано решение "Пропустить" или "Оставить".

Comment: Первый пункт гораздо проще делается кнопкой back.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, уточнил.

Comment: При решении "пропустить" можно выбрать другое решение прям в очереди.

Comment: Если кнопкой назад уже поздно, то просто посмотреть во вкладке "история" соответствующей очереди.